# Why is data in local variable corrupted upon returning from method?

Tags: c++, c++11

Upon testing my C++11 code I encountered a bug whose origin is unclear to me. I have managed to reproduce the bug in the following contrived program.

```
#include <iostream>

class Vector {
    public:
        double* data;
        Vector(int n) {data = new double[n];};
        ~Vector() {delete[] data;}
};

Vector someMethod() {
    if (true) {
        Vector mat {3};
        if (true) {
            mat.data[0] = 0.1;
            mat.data[1] = 0.2;
            mat.data[2] = 0.3;
        } 
        return mat;
    }
}

int main() {
    Vector mat { someMethod() };
    std::cout << mat.data[0] << std::endl;
    std::cout << mat.data[1] << std::endl;
    std::cout << mat.data[2] << std::endl;
    return 0;

}
```

The following output is produced by the program:

```
0
0.2
0.3
*** Error in `./testy': double free or corruption (fasttop): 0x0000000001f75010 ***
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Whereas the output should be:

```
0.1
0.2
0.3
```

It appears that the first value is corrupted. I experimented with different **Vector** lengths, it is always the case that only the first value is corrupted. I have failed to come up with a satisfactory explanation to the above behavior. I suspect it is due to the fact that the **Vector** object is declared and initialized in the block scope of an **if()** statement which is in the block scope of **someMethod()**. However I do not understand why that should be a problem, if indeed it is.

---

**EDIT**

Both solutions presented, the first following the rule of 3/5 and the second following the rule of 0, worked. Thank you! However I am still puzzled as to why this behavior occurs. What mechanism causes the the value to be corrupted? When I invoke the default move constructor in defining the **Vector** object at the start of the main method, what in its default implementation causes this behavior?

Comment: Search for the so-called "Law of Three". Your code violates this fundamental C++ principle.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt It's the law (or rule) of _five_ in C++11 (in C++98 it was three). There's also the rule of zero which is preferable in most cases.

Comment: Agreed, @zenith, to both statements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`someMethod` produces `Vector mat`. This `Vector` is copied to the `Vector mat` inside `main`. Since you didn't specify a copy constructor the compiler gives you the default copy constructor, which just copies every element that `Vector` has, which is `double * data`. After the copy both `Vector`s have a pointer **to the same data**. Then the original `mat` inside `someMethod` is destroyed, meaning its destructor runs, which deletes the data of **both** vectors. Once `someMethod` returns you get a `Vector mat` with an invalid `data` pointer. You then print out the invalid memory, causing undefined behavior. In this particular case the undefined behavior decided to give you slightly wrong output, but it could just as easily caues a segmentation fault.

I hope now it is clear why the fix from zenith corrects the issue.

Comment: Apologies I may have posed my question incorrectly in my edit, I believe to have invoked the 'move' constructor in defining the Vector object at the start of the main method as opposed to the 'copy' constructor since the method returns a temporary object. Does your argument hold in the case of the move constructor?

Comment: @TeodorNikolov Yes. The default move constructor just `std::move`s all members. Since `double *` has no move constructor you get a regular copy.

Answer (score 1):

You need to follow the [rule of three/five/zero](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three), which says

> If a class requires a user-defined destructor, a user-defined copy constructor, or a user-defined copy assignment operator, it almost certainly requires all three.

In C++11, it's five instead of three because of the addition of the move constructor and move assignment operator.

So your class should look like this with the addition of appropriate copy constructor and assignment operator:

```
class Vector {
    public:
        double* data;
        Vector(int n) {data = new double[n];}

        // copy constructor
        Vector(Vector const& source) {
            data = new double[ /* the same `n` as used in to allocate *source.data */ ];
            // copy *data from `source` to this->data
        }

        // copy assignment operator
        Vector& operator=(Vector const& source) {
            delete[] data;
            data = new double[ /* the same `n` as used in to allocate *source.data */ ];
            // copy *data from `source` to this->data
            return *this;
        }

        ~Vector() {delete[] data;}
};
```

You can add move operators to make it more efficient if you want.

---

To summarize the rule of zero:

> Classes that have custom destructors, copy/move constructors or copy/move assignment operators should deal exclusively with ownership (which follows from the [Single Responsibility Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle)). Other classes should not have custom destructors, copy/move constructors or copy/move assignment operators.

It would look like this:

```
#include <memory>

class Vector {
    public:
        std::unique_ptr<double[]> data;
        Vector(int n) {data.reset(new double[n]);}

        // no need to implement move constructor and move assignment operator,
        // the automatically generated ones do the Right Thing because
        // the resource is managed by the unique_ptr

        // copy constructor and copy assignment operator are deleted
        // because unique_ptr enforces the uniqueness of its managed
        // resource

        // if we wanted, we could implement the copy operators to do
        // a deep copy of `data`, then we would just need to declare
        // the move operators `= default` to not have them deleted.

        // no need for destructor: unique_ptr manages the resource
};
```

Comment: Defining the Vector class by explicitly implementing the copy constructor and the copy assignment as suggested in your answer, provided the correct behavior. However I am invoking the 'move' constructor in defining the Vector object at the start of main which is not explicitly implemented, yet the answer is correct. Does that suggest that the 'copy' constructor was invoked instead even though the object returned by 'someMethod()' is temporary?